# how to resolve the max count 25 limitation of watson conversation intent

Tags: watson-conversation

I want to develop one robot using watson conversation, this robot can answer some frequently asked question about my application. Here is my thinking, every question has its own intent, and the answer will be returned by response. but I have over 50 questions, that means I need to define over 50 intents, but watson conversation limited 25 intents for one workspace. Does anyone have any idea about how to resolve it? Thanks.

Comment: This limit applies for free account only, for standard account the limit is removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options for you

1. Purchase Standard plan ($0.0025 USD/API call)Includes upto Up to 2000 Intents.[Check out more on pricing here](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation.html#pricing-block)
2. Link similar questions together and try to reduce the questions.For example, take two questions regarding Bank withdrawals and Bank deposits could be asked in one intent as Bank transaction and then put type of transactions as entities(dialogue box condition as entities).

Answer (score 0):

And besides that limit, there is another one: max 1000 API queries/month. It if fine for a proof of concept or to development phase. If you intend to go to production, you should purchase a plan. https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation.html